# print till a certain number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a way to print the numbers 1-7 on 1 line, then print 8-14 on another, and finally 22-28, and 29-31 to the console. Here is what I have:

```
def check(z,y):
    if x >= (z) and x <= (y) :
        print (str(x) + " ", end="")

for x in range (1, 31):
    check(1,7)
    check(8,14)
    check(22,28)
    check(29,31)
```

this prints all the numbers 1-31 on the same line, but I dont know how to have 1-7 printed on the same line, without having the other numbers printed on the same line too. 
Also, i cant just do print(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
and so forth.

Comment: Why not adding `print('\n')` wherever you need?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that will print numbers 1-7, 8-14, 22-28 and 29-31 each on different lines:

```
[print(i,end="") for i in range(1,8)]
print("")
[print(i,end="") for i in range(8,15)]
print("")
[print(i,end="") for i in range(22,29)]
print("")
[print(i,end="") for i in range(29,32)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question as you have a few unique variables, but we can break down the logic as such:

```
stop_nums = [7, 14, 28]
non_stop_start, non_stop_end = 15, 22
min_range, max_range = 1, 32

for i in range(min_range, max_range):
    if i in stop_nums: # print and go to the next line
        print '{}\n'.format(i)
    elif i in range(non_stop_start, non_stop_end):
        continue # don't print these per requirements
    else:
        print i,  # print on the same line
```

The above will print this:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7

8 9 10 11 12 13 14

22 23 24 25 26 27 28

29 30 31

Comment: what should someone do with given data structures if number of intervals changes?

Comment: Fair point! In my mind, the OP didn't reference a need for configurability so stuck to a solution for the specific desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use something like:

```
def check(z,y):
    for x in range(z,y+1):
        print (str(x) + " ", end="")
    print('\n')

check(1,7)
check(8,14)
check(22,28)
check(29,31)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 

8 9 10 11 12 13 14 

22 23 24 25 26 27 28 

29 30 31 

[Finished in 0.0s]
```